# How to restart webpack dev server programmatically (is the close method just broken?)

Tags: webpack

I'm starting a webpack dev server (v 1.16) like this

```
let compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
let webpackServer = new webpackDevServer(compiler);
webpackServer.listen(program.webpackPort);
```

I'd like to make a change to the entry points and then restart the server. I've seen the invalidate method, but the only way i've seen that used is by calling compiler.apply and then server.invalidate(), and compiler.apply seems to take a plugin.

I've also seen the close method, but that doesn't seem to work. If i close it with no entry point changes, it seems to restart correctly. But as soon as i add the first one, close no longer seems to have any effect (and no console output either). Here's how I used the close method.

```
if(shouldRestart){
    webpackConfig.entry = newEntry;
    webpackServer.close(); //same reference to server as above
    compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
    webpackServer = new webpackDevServer(compiler);
    webpackServer.listen(program.webpackPort);
}
```

I dug into the close method a little more because it seems like it should do what I want. I've seen in new versions that it takes a callback, so I tried passing that.

```
Server.prototype.close = function(callback) {
  this.sockets.forEach(function(sock) {
     sock.close();
  });
  this.listeningApp.close(function() {
     this.middleware.close(callback);
  }.bind(this));
 this.sockets = [];
```

The callback was only called the first time I called close, so the behavior is the same.

I'd be fine with just stopping the dev server and starting a new one with the new webpackConfig, but I don't see an option for doing that (unless that is what close is supposed to do).

[Here's a gist for more detail](https://gist.github.com/bdwain/2f093b3b225dc0aeb5aae27ded347afa)

Comment: You can run it through nodemon to get the effect you want.

Comment: is there an example you can link to @JuhoVepsäläinen? It seems like it's made for watching files update. I'm trying to change the configuration in memory. I also don't need to run a watcher if that's easier. I can restart the server on demand. I just don't know of any way to restart it

Comment: If nodemon won't work for you (worked for me), here's another option: https://gist.github.com/bebraw/a990a206d9b66b14b8e6 .

Comment: hi @JuhoVepsäläinen. Thanks for your help. What version of webpack dev server are you referencing? The line of code you commented to add to the prototype is already there in 1.16.2, which is what i have. 

Please see the question again. I added a bit more detail.

Comment: i was able to get around this issue by opening the webpack dev server in a fork of my application and killing/recreating the fork when i need to update the configuration

Comment: Ok, cool. That example of mine was for webpack 1 but I don't see why it wouldn't work with 2 esp. now that the bug I mentioned at the Gist was fixed.

Comment: The problem with runtime config modifications is that it can screw things up. Webpack's design doesn't allow that very well.

Answer (score 1):

as it's using the [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) which has the invalidate method :

```
webpackServer.middleware.invalidate()
```

Comment: or just webpackServer.sockWrite(webpackServer.sockets,'content-changed')